# Mongoose map attribute coming back as object

Tags: mongoose

So I've defined a schema.. something along the lines of:

```
const StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Student>(
  {
    studentId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    someMap: {
      type: Map,
      of: String,
    },
  },
);
```

If I then persist this.. and reload:

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('key1', 'value1');

await StudentModel.create({studentId, someMap: myMap});

const loadedStudent = StudentModel.findOne({studentId});
```

the 'loadedStudent' doesn't have a map at someMap anymore.. it's just an object:

```
{
   studentId: "xxxx",
   someMap: {
     key1: 'value1'
   }
}
```

instead of

```
{
   studentId: "xxxx",
   someMap: Map(1) { 'key1' => 'value1' }
}
```